# How to unfocus the user from the input box in a confirmation box using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a confirmation box with a input field requesting a date. When the confirmation box appears, the input box is in focus. How do I unfocus it? I need to drop down a calendar when I click on the input field. Here is my relevant code:

```
$(".confirmLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
   document.getElementById('dialog').focus();
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        buttons : {
            "OK" : function() {

                window.location.href =  targetUrl+"/"+"deletedDate"+"/"+document.getElementById('deletedDate').value;
            },
            "Cancel" : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});

function datepicker(){
    $( "#deletedDate" ).datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: "slideDown"
    });
}
```

Comment: read this http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerClickInput.html

Comment: u must write the datepicker link from where u download, there must b documents regarding your need

Answer (score 32):

This should do the trick:

```
.blur();
```

(as was pointed out - this is sufficient)

Comment: Test your own code. Blur is the standard used here, and will work. Focusout doesn't work and won't fire an event.

Comment: gotcha - I've only ever used .blur() so I guess I should have just left that alone.

Comment: Where should i use .blur()  ??

Comment: sorry I should have included this documentation link for your benefit http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur

Answer (score 9):

You can also trigger blur as an event

```
document.getElementById('dialog').blur();
```

Or

```
$('#dialog').blur();
```

Comment: .trigger() *is* a jQuery function.

Answer (score 8):

Use blur() event.

```
 document.getElementById("dialog").blur();
```